# setTimeout and setInterval do not work on iPad scrolling/momentum events?

Tags: javascript, ipad, settimeout, setinterval, touch-event

On an iPad, when the page is 'flicked', the page continues to scroll with momentum. The touchend event fires as soon as the finger leaves the screen, yet a setTimeout or setInterval in that same function / event will only fire once this 'momentum' animation has finished.

Strange no?

```
var touchNo = 0;

function timedCount() {

    touchNo = touchNo + 1;
    console.log(touchNo);
}


function touchLoop() {

    console.log('Finger removed'); // I fire immediately
    setInterval(timedCount, 50); // I don't fire until scrolling is finished
}

document.addEventListener('touchend', touchLoop, false);
```

Comment: i'm just experiencing the same behavior.